# Windows 7 No Network Access using ICS

Tags: windows, internet, xbox360

I have an Xbox 360, and unfortunately, no wireless adapter for said Xbox.

Since I'm cheap, I decided to use my laptop and the Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) option within Windows 7 to share my Internet from my wireless card to my Ethernet port and from there to my Xbox. This setup worked fine for a long time - about a year and a half.

Then, one day last week, it all simply stopped working. I have tried to set it back up the way it was, but my Xbox keeps saying it has an IP error, and on the Network and Sharing Center, it says that my Local Area Network connection has no network access.

I thought it was a problem with my Windows install, and after much hassle over this past weekend I finally have a working clean Windows 7 install.

Comment: Have you run any updates on the Xbox? I believe there was a major update recently, which may have affected this. Also, have you updated your wireless card or Ethernet drivers under Windows? Sometimes this can also wreak havoc.

Comment: Randolph - My xbox has the latest updates as of this weekend, when i took it to a friends house and used his macbook pro to connect to his wireless network. 

as for my laptop, i will try updating the drivers however this issue occurred before I reinstalled Windows (the reason why i reinstalled, actually). One day it was working, and the next day it wasnt. simple as that.

Comment: @RandolphWest, I recently got access to my sisters laptop which also has windows 7 on it. I tested out ICS with her laptop and it worked perfectly. I think the problem is with my LAN Drivers. How can i find out if i have the latest drivers for my LAN port? When i as device manager to update them, it says that it has the latest software installed.

Comment: Perhaps you should roll back to the previous drivers. In Device Manager, go to the properties of the NIC, click on the Driver tab, and press "Roll Back Driver". If it's greyed out (which I doubt), you'll have to go back to the manufacturer's driver disc.

Comment: ok nvm. its definately my ethernet port that is bust. I cant even get a connection through it when i connect it directly to my router. I gave up and just wired some cat5e to my room and plugged it directly into the router. 

thanks all.

now how do i close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok nevermind people. I ended up re-formating my computer and reinstalling windows 7 onto it. That didn't help. So i decided to check my ethernet port. turns out thats probably broken, as i cent get a network connection through it if i connect it to my router. I gave up with this and wired some cat53 cable through the walls to my room and simply directly connected my xbox to the router.

alls good now :)